# Kotlin: Equivalent @escaping of swift exist?

Tags: swift, kotlin

I am looking for the equivalent of the command @escaping for kotlin if it exists?

```
func fetch(response: @escaping (PriceResponse?) -> Void)
```

Comment: What part of @escaping are you trying to capture here? Kotlin's memory management is completely different than Swift's. I would expect every Kotlin closure to the equivalent of escaping (but also that it shouldn't matter). What you're describing in your comments to Pranavan don't sound like escaping. They sound more like a coroutine (which doesn't exist in Swift today).

Comment: @escaping is primarily a thing for Swift internals. Non-escaping closures can be passed as a simple function pointer (and possibly be inlined) – whereas escaping closures needs to be wrapped in an object that captures the state of the scope in which it is declared.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. exists. Also The syntax is similar to swift:

```
fun fetch(callback: (PriceResponse) -> Unit){ }
```

change  `PriceResponse` to whatever you're returning

Also **edited**

Then change your function invocation from `fetch()` to

```
fetch {
    callingYourAPI(here) // or you can get named argument
    // do some more stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about the command @escaping, because in kotlin if I call the response and I want to leave the function I would have to write then return.

Because in my function I have a condition that calls response several times, so every time I have to write return

Comment: @mickael don't you want to implement completion handler in kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about removing the restriction of calling `@escaping` function inside the `fetch()` function - then you don't need to do anything special in Kotlin - just define the function as incoming argument.

Some more theory:

- all closures are considered "escaping" by default.
- however if you would like to define them "non escaping" - you can do it with the help of the `callsInPlace`  contract.

See for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989221/3134602

Answer (score -1):

I think that according to this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html all closures in kotlin are nonescaping and there is no way to make escaping.

UPD: Similar functionality can be achieved with help of kotlin corutines. More you can find here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html

Comment: As far as I can see the Kotlin reference manual doesn't explicitly mention the issue but the implication is all lambda's are what Apple call "escaping" in Swift. This is not surprising at all as that is how lambda's are normally handled in programming languages; the non-escaping/escaping distinction is  Apple surfacing a compiler optimisation which they either: believe should be manual; or cannot make automatic. However as @RobNapier has commented it is unclear that the OP is actually taking about `@escaping` at all...

Comment: It looks, that I misunderstood @escaping notation in swift and you right, that all lamdas are usually implemented as escaping as it in kotlin. And my answer is not correct.